# Longtable Linebreak overflow

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, overflow

I am having some problems with `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test}


\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
\textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{Erfassung} & \textbf{Typ} & \textbf{Spule} & \textbf{Erfassendes Steuerger\"{a}t} \\ 
\hline
B13.1 & Testwelle & Induktiv & - & ESO9 + CRA \\ 
\hline
B13.2 & Testwelle & Induktiv & - & ESO9 + MSI6 \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{}{B1} & \multirow{2}{}{Testwelle} & \multirow{2}{}{Induktiv Doppelspule} & 1 & ESO9 + CRA \\ 
 \cline{4-5}
 &  &  & 2 & MSI6 \\ 
\hline

\end{longtable}\label{tab:table1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the last column the size of the third cell is wrong. The word Doppelspule is overflowing.

Is there a way to fix this without changing the table type or setting the cell size manually?

Comment: Do you get any error messages from the code?

Comment: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.24 \multirow{2}{}{B1}
                        & \multirow{2}{}{Testwelle} & \multirow{2}{}{Indukti...

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case, don't even look at the "output" you get, but fix the error first. In your case, the second argument of the multirow command can not be empty (as it is in your example code). Try using either = or * as the second argument.

Comment: Ah that was the Problem i missed * in \multirow{2}{*}

Comment: if you get any error the pdf output (if any is made) is at best a possible debugging aid. tex makes no attempt to make usable output after an error.  It's best to ask about the error message rather than about the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong syntax for `multirow` cells. Missed are `*` or width of cells. For example: correct syntax is `\multirow{2}{*}{B1}`, not `\multirow{2}{}{B1}` etc. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\thead{Sensor}  & \thead{Erfassung} & \thead{Typ}   
                        & \thead{Spule}     & \thead{Erfassendes Steuerger\"{a}t}   \\
    \hline
B13.1               & Testwelle         & Induktiv 
                    & --                & ESO9 + CRA        \\
    \hline
B13.2               & Testwelle         & Induktiv 
                    & --                & ESO9 + MSI6       \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{B1} & \multirow{2}{*}{Testwelle} & \multirow{2}{5em}{Induktiv Doppelspule}
                    & 1                 & ESO9 + CRA        \\
    \cline{4-5}
                    &   &                   & 2 & MSI6      \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\label{tab:table1}  % <--- wrong position!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\label` for table should be inside or after the caption, and caption has ti be located inside the `table` or `longtable` environment. Since you are not providing any information from which will be clear are you really need `longtable`, maybe you need to add to your table the following preamble:

```
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \caption{My long table}
    \label{tab:table1}                  \\
    \hline
\thead{Sensor}  & \thead{Erfassung} & \thead{Typ}
                & \thead{Spule}     & \thead{Erfassendes Steuerger\"{a}t}   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{My long table (cont.)}   \\
    \hline
\thead{Sensor}  & \thead{Erfassung} & \thead{Typ}
                & \thead{Spule}     & \thead{Erfassendes Steuerger\"{a}t}   \\
    \hline
\thead{Sensor}  & \thead{Erfassung} & \thead{Typ}
                & \thead{Spule}     & \thead{Erfassendes Steuerger\"{a}t}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
% table body
```

Using `longtable`, you need to compile your document at least two times, before the table line up correctly.

Comment: @Sveinung, thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure !  :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting the tabular using [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules and nested tabular instead of [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow). Also, I use `\parbox` inside the cells to break the lines. If you have an updated [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package, you can use fixed width columns to easily line up complicated multispanning rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, array}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}*{3}{l}wc{1.25cm}wl{2.2cm}@{}}
\caption{Long table \label{tab:table1}}\\

\toprule
\small\bfseries Sensor   & \small\bfseries Erfassung & \small\bfseries Typ   & 
\small\bfseries Spule     & \parbox{2cm}{\small\bfseries Erfassendes\par Steuergerät}\\
\midrule
\endhead
B13.1   & Testwelle   & Induktiv  & --   & ESO9 + CRA        \\
B13.2   & Testwelle   & Induktiv  & --   & ESO9 + MSI6       \\
\midrule
B1 & Testwelle & \parbox{2cm}{Induktiv \par Doppelspule} &
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}wl{3.45cm}}{%
     \begin{tabular}{@{}wc{1.25cm}l@{}}
     1 & ESO9 + CRA  \\ \midrule
     2 & MSI6\end{tabular}}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```